# Which layer for a change saving method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance

I'm developing my financial app for simple operations. But I need to be able to make note of any changes made to my records. I use C# ASP.NET for my application code and MS SQL 2014 for my DB.

My question is: which is better ?

Application Layer: write a method in code that creates a record in a history table in DB?

Database Layer: write trigger/procedure that creates a record in a history table in DB ?

My main concern is performance - the app is mounted on a IIS server in my home so i need to fine tune this so it will be lag-less for my users and doesn't put a big workload on my server.

Comment: how often this operation is performed?

Comment: We record about 5 transactions a day, each transaction has about 30(user filled) fields ... so about 150 records a day to the history table.

Comment: That's not something to worry about. Just be consistent in your data access strategy and pick whatever fits better for you. You won't have performance issues because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a lot to do with preferences and maintainability.

For the sake of maintainability, I always go with the Layered approach, myself.

Here's an example why.

Let's say you have your SQL Inserts and updates scattered throughout the code. And then, one day, your database changes in such a way, that you would have to look up each and every one of those inserts and updates, and change all of them one by one.

For the sake of argument, you could also create one function that does all of these inserts and updates, and call that specific function every time from your app. That would work, but could become a clutter as you'll eventually end up with a lot of those functions for different tables, views, etc, ...

Now let's say you have used the layered approach. You would then simply find the class that does all updates and inserts to one specific table and simply do your changes there. The rest of the application perhaps doesn't even need to be aware of this change.

Performance is (in my opinion) not really a factor. Making an object isn't expensive at all, but is hardly measurably as it is. So I'd say go with the layered approach.